# Rails Ajax - load partial view via javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, partial-views

I am building a small twitter-like feed. A user has an input, and you have a feed of inputs.

The feed is effectively a list of posts. Each post's view is defined by a `_post.html.haml` partial view.

I have an AJAX post method that creates a new post in the backend. The problem is that you have to refresh the page to actually view the post appear on the feed.

I would like to append the html to the feed column. However, I create a post on the feed column using a partial view that takes in a local variable of the post details.

Partial views are on the server side. How can I still use the same partial view to obtain the html code for the new post I have created so that I can append it to feed column without having to refresh the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try [render(:update)](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods/replace_html) in the action you post to:

```
render(:update) do |page|
  page.replace_html 'divID', :partial => 'your-partial'
end
```

Comment: This couples the frontend to the backend because the frontend depends on the backend knowing about the frontend's structure.

Comment: Can this be one in jQuery as well? As from the documentation it was written as prototype helper.

Answer (score 1):

Post code snippets so it can easy to answer. Anyway you can do like this. When you are creating a new post using get ajax request it will go into your controller action. In controller action you can do:

```
   def get_new_post   #This is the controller action called by your ajax
     post = Post.create!(ajax_params)
     render :partial => "post", :locals => {:post => post}
   end
```

In view you append the new post to post list as below:

```
$.get("ajax_request", function(data, status){
 if(status=="success"){  //if your ajax is success
   $("#post-list").append(data)  //Assuming post-list is the div id of list of posts
 }
});
```

Comment: how would the render know where exactly to render the partial?

Comment: you will get rendered data in data of your ajax request so you can append it to post list

Comment: this probably could work (will try it out now). I was wondering if you can you replace the html via the controller as shown by adamdunson? It would mean that I would not have to write up the javascript code as shown. I could not get adamdunson's code to work ...

Comment: In adamdunson case might work when you have the partial for list of posts. But when you have partial for displaying single post my solution will work. I think there may be other solutions. But I normally use this one.

Comment: anyway you are creating the post using ajax so it will be the get request so response data will contain the your new post when you do render partial